# Postman interceptor proxy iPhone can't see GET requests

Tags: iphone, rest, postman

I can't see certain `GET` requests from iPhone using **Postman interceptor proxy.**

I'm trying to see certain requests sent from an app on an iPhone in postman app. I've followed the guide on the postman website [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/capturing_http_requests).

- This works great for `POST` requests
- But I'm not able to see any `GET` requests.

I just want to check that this is normal. I did note that in the guide to using the postman built-in proxy that

> *Note: for the Postman native apps, request captures over HTTPS will not work if the website has HSTS enabled. Most websites have this check in place.*

I'd like to know why this would block certain `GET` requests but allow other `POST` requests. Both URL endpoints are `https://` if that helps.

Thanks in advance.